# Export excel on WebAPI and EPPlus with post AJAX

Tags: c#, ajax, excel, asp.net-web-api, epplus

I'm trying to export some data in my page sending a JSON object to my controller, calling this method:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Export([FromBody]List<PivotGridModel> lstPivotGrid)
{

    transporte = GetList();

    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(_Service.Export(transporte.Lista, lstPivotGrid));
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = mediaType;
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = String.Format("Plan_{0:yyyy-MM-dd__HH-mm-ss}.xlsx", DateTime.Now);

    return response;
}
```

The AJAX called when I click in the button 'Export' in my page is this one:

```
// the 'url' is the path of my controller and the 'data' is my object
executePostAjaxDataHeaders: function (url, data, headers) {

    var obj = null;

    utils.vars.callerName = arguments.callee != null && arguments.callee.caller != null ? arguments.callee.caller.name : "";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: headers,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        beforeSend: function () { dxLoadPanel.funcs.show(); },
        complete: function () { dxLoadPanel.funcs.hide(); },
        success: function (data) { obj = data; },
        error: function (request, status, error) { console.log(request); console.log(error); obj = utils.funcs.loadAjaxError(utils.vars.callerName, request, status, error); }
    });

    return obj;
}
```

When I click in the button on my page, the console returns me an error that says:

> Error: Invalid XML: *some random characteres like: �&N��>�*

What am I missing? I wanted to download the file in my page... I was testing it using a 'Get' and calling my controller directly in the URL, but when I changed my method to a post (to get the data on my page) it stopped working.

Comment: Why do use `string` config as a parameter? You can put `List<PivotGridModel> lstPivotGrid` as a parameter. Binder will automatically transform it to the list. You will only need to send the correct `JSON`. And don't forget to add the headers such as `Content-type` and `Accept-type`.

Comment: I was using a list before, i created this model yesterday and forgotted to change the parameter. Thanks for the remember!

Comment: And why do you return `HttpResponseMessage` instead of some model? I think it will be more comfortable to return `ExampleViewModel`. It will also convert to `JSON` on a client side.